# How can I type for a sequence points?

Tags: typography

I am typing the code: `Let A, B, C, D be four points?`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
I tried

Let $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ be four  points.

Let $A,B, C, D$ be four  points.

Let $A\,,B,\, C,\, D\,$ be four  points.
\end{document}
```

What is the best way?
[image]

Comment: I know this has been asked before, I'll see if I can find the question. (And I think the first one is correct.)

Comment: I also think, that the first version is correct.  Especially, if you are looking for a correct structure of your document.

Comment: I also think that the first one is the correct one. The reason: The commas here belong to the sentence, they are not part of the math. That would be different if you were talking about a mathematical object that is a sequence, like $x_1, x_2, x_3$, but you are talking here about 4 distinct points. The last one is wrong because in English there should be no space before a comma.

Comment: I think I'd be inclined to write `Let $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ be ...`, leaving aside my preference for an [Oxford Comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma), the "and" helps remind me that the commas and conjunction are part of my text, not part of the maths.

Answer (score 2):

Correct one is:

`Let $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ be four  points.`